# Designing and using protocol to transfer data

Tags: c#, sockets, protocols

Can anyone share me a link or explain how to design an application protocol and use it over tcp/ip transport protocol using Socket programming ?

Comment: This seems to be a very broad question.  Perhaps you can clarify with the type of application/data you are looking to communicate and what language you are using

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/1059070/arcyqwerty - I am using C#.net and i want to send data from a windows service running in one server to the service running in another server through activemq and save it in their DB. I want a custom application protocol coz i would want to send different types of data and identity them in the second server on parsing the data sent.

Comment: I am not too familiar with C#.net (should tag that if you're asking on that particular language).  Depending on the type of data, there may be some type of serialization function that C# has built in.  Otherwise formats like JSON (or binary form BSON) are pretty cross-platform in terms of transmitting data

Comment: If you are using ActiveMQ as a pubsub, I imagine there is a driver for .Net to communicate with it for you to actually pubsub (http://activemq.apache.org/nms/). That would abstract the socket layer for you. Why do you need to know socket programming over TCP in .Net?